# How do I handle event when user touch up outside the UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk

I have a custom popup menu in my iOS application. It is UIView with buttons on it. How do I handle event when user touch up outside this view? I want to hide menu at this moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should create a custom `UIButton` that takes up the whole screen.  Then add your subview on top of that button.  Then when the user taps outside of the subview they will be tapping the button.

For example, make the button like this:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourhidemethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

(where `yourhidemethod:` is the name of the method that removes your subview.)  Then add your subview on top of it.

---

Update: It looks like you're wanting to know how to detect where touches are in a view.  Here's what you do:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self]; //location is relative to the current view
  // do something with the touched point 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in full-screen transparent view and handle touches for it.

Comment: Oh, thx. But I don't know how to handle ouches on view. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Well you can get what you want without manual touch handling. In that fullscreen view you can also add a `UIButton` instance made with '[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]'. After that all you have to do it to add your controller (or whatever you use to handle this menu) as a target for this button like `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(transparenViewTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`.

Comment: I've asked exactly about manual touch handling. Could you give me some information or link to documentation about this question?

Comment: @miksayer: I added information to my answer.  Ideally the first way I listed it should be the way to do it, no need for detecting the exact location of touches.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have an invisible view(uicontrol) that is as big as the screen which then holds this custom popup.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd be better served by deriving your menu from UIControl rather than UIView. That would simplify the touch handling, and all you'd have to do in this case would be to set a target and action for UIControlEventTouchUpOutside. The target could be the menu itself, and the action would hide or dismiss the menu.