# iOS custom dialog box

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, customdialog

I'm working on an iPhone app in which I'm trying to create a card which will be shown on top of a view and when a touch event happens outside its boundaries, the card needs to be closed. What is the best way of doing it. The card will have a custom background image, a `UIWebview`(which contains a question) and 2 buttons - yes and no.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend to use a separate UIView and show it on a click event. I have this in many apps of mine and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the UIView on top of the current view itself? If yes, I would like to know how. I would not prefer to create a custom view if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView). It's a replacement for UIAlertView.

You may inspire yourself from that example to make one yourself with your specifications.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. For those of you interested, to close the view when a touch happens outside its boundaries, I had to use the idea given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263377/how-do-i-handle-event-when-user-touch-up-outside-the-uiview/5263552#5263552).